# MySQL: Sort most popular names with query, but specific to each IP

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table set up like this:

```
id    |      ip      |   name    
---------------------------------
1     | 54.34.32.222 |   John 
2     | 23.44.64.843 |   Rick 
3     | 54.34.32.222 |   John 
4     | 23.44.64.843 |   John 
5     | 14.432.45.45 |   Lisa 
6     | 54.34.32.222 |   Lisa 
7     | 14.432.45.45 |   Lisa
```

I want to query and sort the most popular names. I do not want to include any more than one IP per name.

For example, "54.34.32.222" appears for John twice, so I only want to grab the first row. But "54.34.32.222" also appears for Lisa, so I would like to grab that IP as well.

The result should look something like this:

```
id    |      ip      |   name    
---------------------------------
1     | 54.34.32.222 |   John 
2     | 23.44.64.843 |   Rick 
4     | 23.44.64.843 |   John 
5     | 14.432.45.45 |   Lisa 
6     | 54.34.32.222 |   Lisa
```

Lisa and John would then be the most popular names, and should appear at the top of the sort, followed by Rick.

I would like my final query to return something that looks like:

```
name     |  count  |
--------------------
Lisa     |    2    |
John     |    2    |
Rick     |    1    |
```

Is it possible to do this in a single query? Or even two? Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: He asked a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37463021/mysql-select-unique-value-in-column-based-on-another-columns-value/37463142#37463142).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can order by the count of distinct ip's per name. In case of a tie with the counts, you can order by name or some other column.

```
select name, count(distinct ip) as cnt
from tablename
group by name
order by cnt desc, name
```

Comment: Would "distinct ip" only grab one IP per query, and not one ip per name?

Comment: it counts distinct ip's by name.